# Последовательность блоков в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Мне нужно чтобы блоки изменяли порядок как на картинке.

а - это `sm`, `md`, `lg`. б - это `xs`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">один</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-6">три</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xs-pull-12">два</div>
</div>
```

Пытаюсь сделать так, но не получается. Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример

```css
[class*=col-]{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">один</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-push-4 col-sm-push-6">три</div>    
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-pull-4 col-sm-pull-4">два</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">один</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-sm-push-6 col-md-4 col-md-push-4">три</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-2 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">два</div>
</div>
```